# Are there some icon resource(free or commercial for wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Are there some icon resource(free or commercial for wp7?

icons for applicationbar and buttons with round border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend here but I like the free icons at http://symb.ly for use with Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

A Few More

[MetroStudio](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) Just sign up and download. It offers options to edit too

[CESPage](http://www.cespage.com/silverlight/appbar.html)

As somebody noted, a lil more googling might help too :)